# @Transactional doesn't open Hibernate Transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I declared Spring Beans in my beans.xml:

```
<context:annotation-config />   
<context:component-scan base-package="com.pack"/>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="transactionManager"
              class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"> 
     <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
     <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
</bean>
```

dataSource and sessionFactory beans:

```
@Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        ds.setUsername(userName);
        ds.setPassword(password);
        ds.setDriverClassName(driverName);
        ds.setUrl(url);
        return ds;
    }

@Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean factory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSourceConfiguration.dataSource());

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        props.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        props.put("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");
        factory.setHibernateProperties(props);
        factory.setMappingResources("com/pack/Item.hbm.xml");

        return factory;
    }
```

If I use sessionFactory and dataSource beans separately they work well. A also have DAO class:

```
@Repository(value = "itemDaoHibernateImpl")
public class ItemDaoHibernateImpl implements ItemDao {

    @Resource(name = "sessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory factory;

    public void setFactory(SessionFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public Session session() {
        return factory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @Override
    public void create(Item item) {
        session().save(item);
    }
```

I don't open the sessions because I want to force Spring to do this. I have Service class with method:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void create(Item item) {
    dao.create(item);
}
```

When I call it, I have the exception:

**`org.hibernate.HibernateException: save is not valid without active transaction`**

I've done  like [this tutorial](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) tells. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Do you inject the class that calls `create(Item item)` ? (I upvote so you get enough reputation to answer in comments)

Comment: Can you please provide your implementation for the `sessionFactory`?

Comment: of course I do. I've updated my question. Take a look my dataSource and sessionFactory beans

Comment: @Transactional is applied using Spring AOP (using JDK proxies per default), do your service implement an interface ? is the call to create external to the service class declaring the create method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove `props.put("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread")` from your sessionFactory configuration. When you are using Spring managed transactions, you don't need it. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Thank you!! Brilliant! It works! But how will spring create a new session if I dont determine that parameter? How will spring create new session by each request? What should I do?

Comment: The SessionFactory is created by Spring using given dataSource and is taking its DB connections from connection pool. We get a Hibernate session via SessionFactory.getCurrentSession(). then start transaction, do the work and then commit() or rollback(), and at the end close the connection(connection object will be returned to the pool). Hibernate session factory will be destroyed/closed when we either stop application or shutdown the server.

Comment: What value should I put in this parameter?

Comment: Don't set anything for Spring managed transactions, with @Transactional.

Comment: Spring has [its own implementation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/SpringSessionContext.html) of the `CurrentSessionContext` interface from hibernate. This is set by default, as soon as you start messing around with the `current_session_context_class` property this will not be the case, so as a general rule of thumb when using Spring don't set that property.

Answer (score 0):

When I have come across this before it is due to whether Spring is using CGLib or Javassist to augment your class to provide transactionality. if I remember correctly if you only have Javassist in then the class that Spring needs to create the proxy on in order to implement the Transactional annotation must implement an interface.